# Cannot draw E/R diagram for many entities with same attributes

Tags: database, entity-relationship, erd

How can I draw an E/R diagram for my database that contains three entities and the have the same attributes. A videogame scores and the entities are the accounts for users like normal accounts, hardcore and solo

Comment: If they contain the same data but are a different type or classification, why not add a a column for classification. Don’t split like data by type or status. Or link to an associative table which has the account types to resolve the M:M

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.